# What is the correct mypy annotation for a tuple where one member's type is conditioned on another member's value?

Tags: python, types, mypy

**Update (2023-08-28 2:48 PM):** Responding to Jason Harper's logical-but-sadly-not-working suggestion about using literals with more details and a better example.

---

I'm trying to create a rust-esque expectation tuple with two possible return values that will be returned from functions manipulating a finite state machine:

- `(False, None)` on failure
- `(True, int)` on success.

How do I define a mypy type such that mypy will correctly narrow to
the expected type for the second value, given the first? Using `Literal[False]` and `Literal[True]` doesn't seem to work, as illustrated in the below toy example:

Example use:

```py
from typing import Literal, Optional, Tuple, Union
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

StatusType = Union[Tuple[Literal[False], None], Tuple[Literal[True], int]]

def try_to_check_status(test_val: int) -> StatusType:
    """Check if test_val is positive"""
    if test_val < 0:
        return False, None
    return True, test_val


def main() -> None:
    """Entry point"""

    ok, status = try_to_check_status(-1)
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        reveal_type(ok)      # mypy should reveal that this is a bool 
        reveal_type(status)  # mypy should reveal that this is None
    print(f"{ok}, {status}")

    ok, status = try_to_check_status(1)
    if TYPE_CHECKING:
        reveal_type(ok)      # mypy should reveal that this is a bool
        reveal_type(status)  # mypy should reveal that this is an int
    print(f"{ok}, {status}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When run with mypy:

```bash
$ mypy status_check.py
status_check.py:21: note: Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
status_check.py:22: note: Revealed type is "Union[None, builtins.int]"  # I want this to be None! 
status_check.py:27: note: Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
status_check.py:28: note: Revealed type is "Union[None, builtins.int]"  # I want this to be builtins.int!
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

What's the right annotation here?
Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: Would you mind providing some more context of how this tuple is used? E.g. will it be created as a function output?

Comment: `Union[Tuple[Literal[False], None], Tuple[Literal[True], int]]` perhaps?

Comment: Literal sound good! I'll test it.

Comment: Alas, `Literal` didn't work. I've built out the example a bit more.

Comment: Wen you unpack union of tuples, every item is inferred as corresponding union. There is no type dependency backtracking in `mypy`. If I understand what you mean, the workaround could be something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=a1d868adb0a9552e7ba56a1453b1cb8c).

Comment: (of course, you can't expect `f(-1)` to be `tuple[False, None]` and `f(1)` - `tuple[True, int]` - `-1` and `1` are not types, but values.)

Comment: “Of course” seems surprising: Python lets you condition a return type on parameter value, so the type checking should be flexible enough to account for that.